# Rebase algorithm

Tags: solidity, tokens, math, algorithm

I'm building a rebase token and need some help with the algorithm. These are the variables, constants, and constraints (the values themselves are just examples):

```js
Set of variables 1:
```

- a1 = 1934464428151493937044
- b = 54802476401439357
- c = 1e18
- result1 = ?

```js
Set of variables 2:
```

- a2 = 1837741206733939183658
- b = 54802476401439357
- c = 1e18
- result2 = ?

Final invariant --> `result1 == result2`

As you can see `b` and `c` are constants and the only variables shared between sets, so you can't use `a1` during the operations of `Set 2` and vice versa (`a1` and `a2` might fluctuate in value, but not `b` and `c`).

Also, `result1` is not known during the operations for `result2`, and vice versa.

The idea is to have `result1` to equal `result2`. Feel free to add more variables, constants, escalating factors, etc. if you need them in order to achieve the final idea.

Thanks!